# Availability Monitor Plugin issue -- Dynatrace Client 6.1.0

Tags: .net, dynatrace

Dynatrace Client 6.1.0

I just want to test if server can be pinged or not.
I have installed a Availability Monitor Plugin,create a monitor URL and did following settings:

1. Check the checkbox for **Execute Ping test** settings Name
2. Set Ping Wait Time(secs) value to 5
3. In Host section I added host which I selected from Host dialog under Windows node.( Instead of existing selection can I create a new host with my website complete URL for example www.sample.com )
4. In Measure tab I added one measure **Availability** and added values as per given below:
   [image]
5. Then I created incident and added Availability measure in Condition tab and set Aggregation value to **last**.
6. In Action tab I put my email for notification and finally clicked on Apply and OK.

Immediately after this I got incident email and voiolation message is:
Was 0.00 % but should be higher than 0.00 %.

Even I checked website is loading fine.

Did I miss something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best place for these question would be our Dynatrace Discussion forum @ http://answers.dynatrace.com.
In your case it would be interesting to look at the output of the Availabilty Monitor plugin. Maybe the plugin actually failed to execute the ping, e.g: the host name couldnt be resolved. These details can be seen in either the log file that the monitor creates or in the Details section of your Monitor Executions.

If you have further questions I do recommend though to post it on answers.dynatrace.com

Andi